# Installation issues on unsupported MacBook 5,1 using Dosdude ´s mojave patch

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, install

I am a newbie and this is my first post. I have been using my old MacBook successfully for a few month on dosdude ´ s 1.2.3 patch. My unibody MacBook has been upgraded  with 5 GB of ram and 256 SSD, with macOS Extended.
Everything was smooth.

Yesterday, I realized I needed to upgrade the system to get to 10.4.16 and I followed the tutorial again to install the 1.3.0 patcher skipping the clean install parts as was suggested in my case.

I think I did everything ok until I tried to do the final reboot after the patches. Then the progression bar halfway through went to a black screen with the little wheel turning then stopping then turning then stopping with the mouse icon appearing and disappearing at the same time...

I did try :

- multiple reboot: no improvement
- disk repair: showed no problem
- safe mode: I can boot into it. I reinstalled the patch updater from the website to have the final version, reinstalled all the patches. In about a Mac, I can see I am indeed in version 10.4.16.
- verbose mode shows something I do not get( please see caption)

  I would like to try to avoid a clean install as it will be difficult to save my data (I am on holiday) and also I am scared that I won't be able to log in even in safe mode.[image: verbose mode]

If anyone has an idea, I will be very grateful.

Many Thanks !

Comment: Have you contacted dosdude for his take?

Comment: Hi Allan, yes I did...

Comment: And the developer said....

Comment: Oh, he has not replied yet, hence my posting here. I really need to be able to use my MacBook ´ normally’ asap for work so I Keep investigating. 
I have contacted a support seller who won’t take it in, as expected. Checking the last line of code on the internet, it seems that it is an Nvidia clash with Mojave which leaves me even more confused.

Comment: People don't like dealing with "bodged" systems like this this one - your support seller doesn't want to touch it.  If this is for work, the very last thing you should be doing is using this patch to make a laptop run an unsupported version of the OS.  When all is said and done, Mojave (assuming because Tiger 10.4.x is long since out of date) is not compatible with your Mac.  There's simply too many questionable variables to account for to solve the issue.  Maybe you'll get lucky, but again, if this is for work, you should stick with a system that works, not one you're playing around with.

Comment: Thanks Allan, I did understand the risks I am taking and just posted here in case someone would be interested in helping out.